# When is in register possitive number and when negative in assembler

Tags: assembly

Can someone explain me how works +- in registers in assembler? When I have code:

```
mov al, 2
   mov bl, 4
   mov cl, 100
   mul cl
   add ah, bl
mov al, 2
   mov bl, 4
   mov cl, 100
   mul cl
   add ah, bl
```

In the end after multiply it shows me in SASM that in AL is -56. Why? In binary there is 11001000. And I know that this is in addictional code -56. But how can I know if it is this and not 200?

Comment: Whether values in registers should be interpreted as signed or unsigned depends on the context. (following instructions, for example)

Comment: It's up to you, the programmer, to decide if the number is meant to be signed or not.

Comment: The debugger doesn't know whether to show you the number as signed or as unsigned (hence most debuggers offer hex, so you can interpret yourself.). Your program should know how to interpret the registers, as to whether they are signed, unsigned, characters, enum values, etc..  As unsigned, that value is 200.  Btw, `mul` is for unsigned multiplication, and, in the form you're using it takes 2 8-bit inputs, and produces a 16-bit output (in `AX`); this is known as a widening multiplication.  `imul` is for signed multiplication, also widening.  If you take `al` alone, you risk truncation/overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of numeric representation of data is just for the user to enjoy (i.e., -35, or 58, or 0xABCD, etc). In general the computer does not care about signedness of data.

[Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is very, VERY commonly used in computing. The basics of 2's complement is that the MSB of your data defines the "sign" -- in your case, 0b11001000's MSB is a 1, so when representing that data your simulator/machine/whatever you're using to look at that value will go "oh hey, there's a 1 in the MSB! Let's interpret this as negative!" and then the "true" value can be calculated by inverting the data (so now, 0b00110111) and adding 1 (0b00111000). That new value (decimal 56) *can* be interpreted with the original value's MSB (a 1, so you can think it's negative), and it might get displayed as -56.

The representation of data ultimately depends on what kind of instructions and operations you are doing with that data. Also note that you are using 8 bit registers. Again, commonly, if you are using an N-bit sized piece of data (in your case, 8 bit registers; frequently you will see 16/32/64-bit registers) the MSB of that register *may* be used to determine the sign.

As other answers have said, the interpretation of the data depends on context. Some instructions may interpret values as signed/unsigned (lots of math operations) and some instructions may ignore signedness entirely because it's not relevant to the operation (if you were using a register as a memory address, like `mov eax, [ebx+4]`)